# Relabel samples in kmean results considering the order of centers

Tags: r, classification, k-means

I am using kmeans to cluster my data, for the produced result I have a plan.

I wanted to relabel the samples based on ordered centres. Consider following example :

```
a = c("a","b","c","d","e","F","i","j","k","l","m","n")
b = c(1,2,3,20,21,21,40,41,42,4,23,50)

mydata = data.frame(id=a,amount=b)
result = kmeans(mydata$amount,3,nstart=10)
```

Here is the result :

```
clus$cluster 
2 2 2 3 3 3 1 1 1 2 3 1

clus$centers
1 43.25
2  2.50
3 21.25


mydata = data.frame(mydata,label =clus$cluster)
mydata
    id amount  label
1   a      1        2
2   b      2        2
3   c      3        2
4   d     20        3
5   e     21        3
6   F     21        3
7   i     40        1
8   j     41        1
9   k     42        1
10  l      4        2
11  m     23        3
12  n     50        1
```

What I am looking for is sorting the centres and producing the labels accordingly:

```
1  2.50
2  21.25
3  43.25
```

and label the samples going to:

```
1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 1 2 3
```

and the result should be :

```
    id amount  label
1   a      1        1
2   b      2        1
3   c      3        1
4   d     20        2
5   e     21        2
6   F     21        2
7   i     40        3
8   j     41        3
9   k     42        3
10  l      4        1
11  m     23        2
12  n     50        3
```

I think it is possible to do it by, order the centres and for each sample  taking the index of minimum  distance of samples with centres as the label of that cluster.

Is there another way that R can do it automatically ?

Comment: I see you unchecked the answer but you did not accepted another. Is there a problem?

Comment: Yes, there was a problem, but I am not sure for now, I will inform you when I got the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One idea is to create a named vector by matching your centers with the sorted centers. Then match the vector with `mydata$label` and replace with the names of the vector, i.e.

```
i1 <- setNames(match(sort(result$centers), result$centers), rownames(result$centers))

as.numeric(names(i1)[match(mydata$label, i1)])
# [1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `for` loop, if you don't mind loops

```
cls <- result$cluster
for (i in 1 : length(result$cluster)) 
     result$cluster[cls == order(result$centers)[i]] <- i

result$cluster
#[1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 1 2 3
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, the answer is correct and useful