# K-means sort labels

Tags: matlab, label, cluster-analysis, k-means

Assume I have matrix `A` and I perform K-means clustering on them in MATLAB. I get the following

```
A=

 1    20     5
 1    30    10
 2    60    20
 5   100    45
```

`kmeans(A,4)` results in the following labels:

```
 2
 4
 3
 1
```

Now I permute rows of `A` and I get matrix `B`:

```
B =

 2    60    20
 1    30    10
 5   100    45
 1    20     5
```

and after applying the `kmeans` the labels are `B1 = [3 1 2 4]`, which seems to be random assignment. For example second row of matrix `A` is in cluster `4` but second row of matrix `B` which is the same thing as second row of `A` is in cluster `1`.

How can I get the labels in the `kmeans` such that rows that have highest value always get the same label, for example `3`, and row that have lowest value always get `1`?

For example the last row of `A` gets label `3`, thus the third row of `B` also get label `3`.

Comment: So you want to sort the k mean vectors according to their norm? What if two vectors have the same norm? There is no unique ordering for dimensions >= 2.

Comment: In this case the labeling do not make any sense. I want something like this if second row of matrix A is in cluster 2 and third row of matrix C also has a similar behavior should be also clustered in 2.

Comment: You ask for 4 clusters, you get 4 clusters. K-means doesn’t guess at how many clusters are meaningful.

Comment: What about these answers or similar in R : what is the approach behind this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48182601/relabel-samples-in-kmean-results-considering-the-order-of-centers?rq=1

Comment: That is 1D data. You can impose some sort of ordering in 3D (as in your example), but is it a useful ordering? For example lexicographical ordering, or on norm but desambiguate based on lexicographical ordering. You need to define “higher” and “lower” in the context of your question.

Comment: what about finding the Euclidean distance to center and sort it according to that. I am not just really sure . I just have an idea.

Answer (score 2):

Each label is tied to the mean of a cluster. To sort the labels, you sort the means in e.g. order of appearance along a given axis (x-axis in this example). Here's an implementation in Python:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs

np.random.seed(1)

def rearrange_labels(X, cluster_labels, sort_on_column=0):
    labels, ctrs = [], []
    for i in range(len(set(cluster_labels))):
        Xi = X[cluster_labels == i]
        ctr = np.mean(Xi, axis=0)
        labels.append(i)
        ctrs.append(ctr)

    ctrs = np.row_stack(ctrs)
    labels = np.array(labels).reshape(-1, 1)

    # sort on x column
    new_order = ctrs[:, sort_on_column].argsort()

    labels_new = labels[new_order]
    ctrs_new = ctrs[new_order]

    np.put(cluster_labels, labels, labels_new)
    return cluster_labels, ctrs_new


X, _ = make_blobs(n_samples=500, centers=10, n_features=2)

clf = KMeans(n_clusters=10)
cluster_labels = clf.fit_predict(X)

cluster_labels, ctrs = rearrange_labels(X=X, cluster_labels=cluster_labels)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i, m in enumerate(ctrs):
    ax.annotate(
        xy=m[[0, 1]],
        s=i,
        bbox=dict(boxstyle="square", fc="w", ec="grey", alpha=0.9),
    )
ax.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=cluster_labels)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The cluster numbers assigned by k-means do not have an order - don't treat them as such. They are numbers just for convenience, they might as well be A B C D.

If *you* want to impose an order on them, you can relabel them as you want. You can sort the centers by X coordinate, and relabel them. It's not the job of k-means to do so, you need to do this yourself.

Comment: Can you show me a piece of code, I have an idea i am not just sure how exactly to implement that

Comment: I don't use Matlab.